# itemize: how to control spacing in longer items?

Tags: itemize

How can I also reduce the spacing in longer items? What is missing in my MWE? Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}      

\begin{document}
\newenvironment{newitemize}
{ \begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{-1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{-1pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{-1pt}     }
{ \end{itemize}                  } 

\begin{newitemize}
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{newitemize}

\end{document}
```

Edit:

To have a uniform appearance, I would like to adapt the line interspaces in the long items to the line interspaces between the short items:

[image]

Comment: Which spacing, exactly?

Comment: Is there a reason for the negative spaces? I can find none.

Comment: Do you really want to reduce the baseline skip in lists? You could use, e.g., `\linespread{.9}\selectfont`. But I wouldn't. And I wouldn't use negative values for the other skips. BTW: Do you know [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `enumitem` and its option `nosep`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

or, if you like to use your definition of `itemize`, with reduced vertical spaces:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\newenvironment{newitemize}
{ \begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemsep}{-2pt} % <-- existed vertical spaces are reduced for 2pt
\addtolength{\parskip}{-2pt}
\addtolength{\parsep}{-2pt}     }
{ \end{itemize}                  }

\begin{newitemize}%[nosep]
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{newitemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to reduce not only the skip before and between items to a negative value, but also the normal line skip, you can just reduce the line skip and set all other skips to 0pt

```
\documentclass[BCOR8mm]{scrbook}      
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Normal list without sep:}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{itemize}
\paragraph{List without sep and reduced line skip:}
\begin{itemize}[nosep,before=\linespread{0.9}\selectfont]
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can play with th keys of `enumitem`, and if you want to change line spacing within item, use `setstretch`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{1cm}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{itemize}[nosep, topsep=1.4pt, before=\setstretch{0.9}]
\item Christopher Columbus was born in Italy in 1451
\item He was the first European since the Vikings to sail across the Atlantic Ocean to America
\item Columbus was sure that he could sail west to find a new route
\item In 1492, Columbus set sail with three sailing ships. After 36 days the crew sighted land, in the Bahamas. The local people were amazed to see the strangers. Columbus called the local people Indians, for he believed he had reached the Indies. In fact, he had discovered a new world – America.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernhard, thank you very much for your help!!